# Coin toss/Who wants to be a Billionaire

Tags: python

PROBLEM:
You are given a unique investment opportunity.
Starting with euro 1 of capital, you can choose a fixed proportion, f, of your capital to bet on a
fair coin toss repeatedly for 1000 tosses.
Your return is double your bet for heads and you lose your bet for tails.
For example, if f = 1/4, for the first toss you bet euro 0.25, and if heads comes up you win euro 0.5
and so then have euro 1.5. You then bet euro 0.375 and if the second toss is tails, you have 1.125.
Choosing f to maximise your chances of having at least euro 1,000,000,000 after 1,000 flips, what
is the chance that you become a billionaire?
All computations are assumed to be exact (no rounding), but give your answer rounded to 12
digits behind the decimal point.

I have researched looking for published/scholar materials on implementing this in python, couldn't get anywhere. Could someone help me out.

Comment: Well, the real problem is that you posted your homework to SO without trying anything to solve it. I suggest you make an attempt at solving this and when you have an _actual_ problem, come back with details and you'll be helped.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @xxbbcc, im just getting started on it. I posted the actual problem to see if i can get any pointers / ideas on getting started. Im fairly new to python programming. this is only my second task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing the simulation is easy - im having trouble figuring out the optimization, i tried .4 to .1 for the pct multiplier and alway made over 1 billion in well less than 1000 tries:

```
from random import randint

x = 1.0   # 1 euro
pct = .25 # 1/4

for i in range(1000): # 0-999 = 1000
    bet = x * pct
    if randint(0,1) == 1: # assume 0 = tails 1 = heads
        x += bet*2
    else:
        x -= bet

    if x > 1000000000.0:
        break

print i,x
```

notice i stop once i get to a billion - the numbers get crazy big if you go to 1000 iterations